# How can I force automatic table numbering to correspond to a chapter number? (so instead of table 1, I should get table 2.1)

Tags: tables, numbering

I am using `\documentclass[]{article}` and want to force automatic table numbering to correspond to a section number.

That is, instead of table 1, I should see table 2.1 (in chapter 2) in the caption and when I `\ref{}`.

I am sorry for the simple question, but I don't know how to google this evidently. Thank you!

Comment: `article` class does not have chapters

Comment: `\counterwithin{table}{section}` for sections

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

in the preamble